# Bifurcation in a linear system with 2 equations and 1parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

I have the following system $$\frac{dx}{dt} = ax+y$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dt} = -x+ay$$ By setting the derivative equals to $0$, we get the equilibrium point $(0,0)$. After drawing the phase portrait for various parameter $a$, we conclude that $(0,0)$ is stable when $a<0$ (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWfJc.png)), a center when $a=0$ (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD46U.png)), and unstable when $a>0$ (see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGVyO.png)). Also, the eigenvalues are $\lambda = a \pm i$.

Do we have a bifurcation here? I was guessing that maybe we have Hopf bifurcation when $a=0$ because $(0,0)$ lose its stability when $a=0$. If it's true, I was also asked to draw the bifurcation diagram. I am not sure what it means or how to draw it.

Comment: We do have a bifurcation here since equilibrium's stability has changed. However, it's not a Hopf bufurcation: since the system is linear for all values of $a$, there is no limit cycle (isolated closed trajectory). Also, typically at critical value for Hopf bifurcation we have a degenerate focus, not a center as here. I think you can take a look at simplest bifurcation diagrams in Strogatz's book.

Comment: @Evgeny was the book you refer to is Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos: With Applications To Physics, Biology, Chemistry, And Engineering by Steven H. Strogatz? and just to clarify, so Hopf bifurcation could only occur when the system is nonlinear?

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the book I was referring to. And yes, Hopf bifurcation (changing stability of equilibrium by emerging/colliding with limit cycle) can happen only when system is nonlinear: linear systems don't have limit cycles.